# Python flash text, or make text disappear once printed

Tags: python-3.x, list

I've got some text I'm printing to the user, but I want the text to then disappear or flash, so that they can then remember what sequence the colours were in (it's a memory game). The text I want to flash/disappear is a list.

Is there a way to do that?

tia

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not much you can do, you can't completely erase it, but anyways you can always do this:

```
import os
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

I hope this fulfills your need.